# Can scikit-learn 'dummy classifier' be applied to multiclass scenario

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, multiclass-classification

I understand that **dummy classifier** https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.dummy.DummyClassifier.html gives a measure of baseline performance and it applies different strategies to predict.

Have found examples of its application in binary class problems. Wanted to understand can this classifier be used in a multiclass scenario. If yes, how would `stratified` strategy work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DummyClassifier` indeed supports multiclass classification. Here is a small example:

```py
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.dummy import DummyClassifier


X, y = make_classification(n_classes=3, n_clusters_per_class=1, random_state=42)

clf = DummyClassifier(strategy='stratified')
clf.fit(X, y)
```

It even supports multiclass-multioutput classification as its `fit` method accepts `y` of the following shape:

> **y: array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)**

---

To understand the `stratified` strategy, you might want to consult the [user guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#dummy-estimators):

> `stratified` generates random predictions by respecting the training set class distribution

So the predictions will be random but still in accordance with the distribution of classes in the training set, as you can see here:

```py
print(np.unique(y, return_counts=True))
# output: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([34, 33, 33])) 

print(np.unique(clf.predict(X), return_counts=True))
# output: (array([0, 1, 2]), array([32, 38, 30]))
```